# PLS-00540: Object not supported in this context while trying to compile package specification

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to compile a package specification. I would like to include some type definitions and declare a function:

```
TYPE col_type AS OBJECT (
col_name VARCHAR2(50)
);

TYPE col_sub_type
IS TABLE OF
col_type;

FUNCTION get_col_tab RETURN col_sub_type;
```

And finally, the `get_col_tab` function:

```
FUNCTION get_col_tab RETURN col_sub_type AS
l_type  col_sub_type := col_sub_type();
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME t_name FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_1') LOOP
l_type.extend;
l_type(l_type.last) := col_type(i.t_name);
END LOOP;
RETURN l_type;
END;
```

But when compiling the package specification I get the following error:

> PLS-00540: Object not supported in this context

As I understand I cannot use a type `OBJECT` in package specification. Is there a workaround or another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Within PL/SQL, you have to use `record` instead of `object`.

```
TYPE col_type IS RECORD (
col_name VARCHAR2(50)
);

TYPE col_sub_type
IS TABLE OF
col_type;

FUNCTION get_col_tab RETURN col_sub_type;
```

While there are some functional differences, if you're just looking to create a group of column definitions, they are effectively the same.

---

One of those differences is that the `record` type does not support constructors (either implicit or explicit). This means you'll need to assign each field individually:

```
l_type(l_type.last).col_name := i.t_name;
```

An alternative is to use `bulk collect`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name t_name
BULK   COLLECT INTO l_type
FROM   all_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'TABLE_1';
```

Comment: Package specification compiles well now, thanks, but when I try to compile the package body I get the following: `PLS-00222: no function with name 'COL_TYPE' exists in this scope`

Comment: I have extended my question by adding the whole `get_col_tab` function.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use an object?

Simply do

```
TYPE col_sub_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

and then

```
FUNCTION get_col_tab RETURN col_sub_type AS
l_type  col_sub_type;
BEGIN

   SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_type
   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_1';

   RETURN l_type;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still - there is a new problem. `Function get_col_tab cannot be used in SQL`...

Comment: You must also declare your function in package not only in the package body.